# Create A Union B like output structure by joining two tables on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Joining Two Tables using two fields with different names not working

I have two tables,

a: table with demand by the hour

```
-----------------------------------------
datetime        | customer | pastdemand | levelOfDetail |   
-----------------------------------------
04-01-2019 06:00 | 444111 | 100 | 6 |   
.........   
04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 150 | 6 |
```

here I can have two levels 6 or 24. I am only interested in level=6.
table b: is a log of stored future values by customer.

```
-----------------------------------------
forecastdatetime        | custNumber | forecast | dateGenerated   
-----------------------------------------
04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 120 | 04-29-2019 18:00   
..........   
05-01-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
05-02-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
05-03-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
05-04-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
05-05-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
........
```

The query:

```
 SELECT a.[datetime],a.customer
  [demand]
  ,b.*

  FROM a
  full outer join b on a.customer=b.custNumber
  and a.datetime=b.forecastdatetime
```

I'm getting results that look like a left join.

```
----------------------------------------------------
datetime| customer| pastdemand | forecastdatetime|custNumber|forecast| dateGenerated    
-----------------------------------------   

04-01-2019 06:00 | 444111 | 100 | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL   
......   
04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 150 | 6 | 04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 120 | 04-29-2019 18:00
```

I wanted to create A U B table as in all values from A + values common in A & B based on a match of customer=custNumber and datetime=forecastdatetime for each date generated. 
Expected Result:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
    datetime| customer| pastdemand | forecastdatetime|custNumber|forecast| dateGenerated    
    -----------------------------------------   

    04-01-2019 06:00 | 444111 | 100 | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL   
    04-02-2019 06:00 | 444111 | 100 | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL   
    ......   
    04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 150 | 6 | 04-30-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 120 | 04-29-2019 18:00   
    NULL | NULL |NULL | NULL | 05-01-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
    NULL | NULL |NULL | NULL | 05-02-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
    NULL | NULL |NULL | NULL | 05-03-2019 18:00 | 444111 | 140 | 05-01-2019 18:00   
    NULL | NULL |NULL | NULL |  ..........
```

As you notice, I'm not getting the part of table B that is not common in A.
I realize that for using union the field names need to be the same, in this case, they are not. Would be happy to work around

Comment: Edit our question and show the results you want to get.

Comment: You don't need "right join"?

Comment: I need left + common + right

Comment: The question is a little bit confused. Based on your Expected Result you want to accomplish FULL table JOIN. The full outer join is asking for everything from table A and everything from table B. If they have matching values, match them up. If they don't match, still display the row, but show nulls where they don't match.
You can use the keyword FULL OUTER JOIN or just FULL JOIN in the query.

Comment: It looks like your query is almost fine related with the join syntax. What you need to fix is your select for the columns. To get your expected result just change to `select * from ...` rather than `select a.[datetime],b.* ...`

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic yes, thats what I want.

Comment: Ok, just replace SELECT part as thebrownkid suggest anf you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question and your thoughts on the comment section, it seems like the issue isn't related with the `SQL JOIN` syntax. The problem is related to the select call you are doing for the columns -

```
SELECT * FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.customer = b.custNumber
and a.datetime = b.forecastdatetime
```

> Change made is to retrieve all columns, matching and non-matching using `select * ...`